# handle orientation with multiple stack of viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, orientation

Some quick issues, i have `5 VC` on stack. when i am in my second VC, then if i rotate to landscape and when i move to `1st` VC my layout is totally collapsed.

in my second VC i added `viewWillTransition` and i am `invalidateLayout`of my table view. And if i add `tableview.reloaddata()` in my first screen viewWillAppear .Then it's fine.

But consider if i have 5 VC on stack i can not write code in all VC. Is there any better way to handle it.

Comment: You have to write code in all VC.

Comment: *"when i move to `1st VC` my layout is totally collapsed"* --- What do you mean by that? Can you show images? If you have your constraints setup correctly, auto-layout will handle it without needing any code. Show how your `1st VC` looks in Portrait, show how it looks "collapsed" in landscape, and also show how you think it *should* look in landscape.

Comment: @DonMag my 1st vc table view cell are not in proper ui.

Comment: @teja - yes, your cells are "not in proper ui" ... so you have to ***show us*** what is happening. If you have constraints setup correctly, auto-layout handles rotation without additional code. But, we have no idea what is not "proper" unless you show us.

Answer (score 1):

In your app delegate add this....

```
    var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return self.orientationLock
    }
    struct AppUtility {
        static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {
            if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
                delegate.orientationLock = orientation
            }
        }

        static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask, andRotateTo rotateOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation) {
            self.lockOrientation(orientation)
            UIDevice.current.setValue(rotateOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
        }
    }
```

Used this from any view controller like this...

```
AppDelegate.AppUtility.lockOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait, andRotateTo: UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait)
```

Comment: can u please elobrate what exactly u r trying to say. Bec i already changed my second vc to landscape. But when i move to 1st vc its in landscape mode only...only my table view cell are not properly alligned .

Comment: where i have to add `AppDelegate.AppUtility.lockOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait, andRotateTo: UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait)
`

Comment: @teja You can add this on your viewWillAppear  this line mens a your view lock to portrait mode and rotate to portrait. AppDelegate.AppUtility.lockOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait, andRotateTo: UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait)

Comment: Isn't this `UIDevice.current.setValue(rotateOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")` bad practice? `UIDevice.currentDevice.orientation` is read only. I didn't know that I could change a property that is ready only by setting its value by using its key. Can this break in the future if apple change the key name or sth?