# How can I rotate ViewController in Xcode 11?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, rotation, screen-orientation

I am refactoring my code in Xcode 11. I have a problem with rotation in my App. In Xcode version less than 11 it works fine. I want to programatically set only one ViewController to Landscape mode, instead of Portrait. This code worked fine for older versions...

```
private func setupLandscape() {
        let valueFirst = UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue

        UIDevice.current.setValue(valueFirst, forKey: "orientation")
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .landscapeRight
}
```

EDIT: I solved it. You have to present ViewController to fullScreen mode. Then it works the same as Xcode 10 and less

Comment: take a look here :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57771250/5362750

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work